# How to scrapy table data from html

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, html-table

I have scrapy multi tables from a html. Example for follow images:

[image]

I only scrapy from table[6] ---- table[20] ....  .

Write following xpath get table[6] .. table[20] does not work.

```
def parse_item(self, response):
        trs = response.xpath("/html/body/table[4]/tr/td[1]/table")
        for i in trs:
            item = CompanyItem()
            item['collection_dt'] = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(time.time()))
            item['company_hangye'] = '新能源(储能,太阳能,风能,光伏,新材料等)'
            item['company_quyue'] = i.xpath("/tr/td[1]/table[1]/tr/td[1]/text()").extract()
            item['company_name'] = i.xpath("/tr//td[1]/table[1]/tr/td[1]/strong/a/text()").extract_first()
            item['company_product'] = i.xpath("/tr//td[1]/table[4]/tr/td[1]/text()").extract()
            item['company_qiyeleixing'] = i.xpath("/tr//td[1]/table[5]/tr/td[2]/text()").extract()
            item['company_description'] = i.xpath("/tr//td[1]/table[2]/tr/td[1]/text()").extract()
            lianxi = i.xpath("/tr/td[1]/table[3]/tr/td[1]/text()").extract()
            item['company_lianxi_emp_name'] = lianxi[1]
            item['company_lianxi_tel'] = lianxi[2]
            item['company_lianxi_mobile'] = lianxi[3]
            return item
```

Comment: Have you used a tool like FireBug for Firefox or the scrapy shell to try to debug your xpaths? The screenshot of the web page isn't very useful, can you post some of the HTML?

Comment: A link would be nice as well